# Angularjs:How to pass scope value to directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have written a directive to show the common template for records.
And i am trying to catch the value of newly set `$scope`,but every times it prints my initially defined `$scope`.

**Here how i am doing**

```
$scope.commonExamTemplate    =false;
$scope.examReportHolder      =[];
$scope.examReportHolderCode  =0;

$scope.examSchedule=function(forDay){

angService.getfromRemote('exam/'+forDay)
      .success(function(response){

            console.log(response.success);    
            $scope.commonExamTemplate    =true;
            $scope.examReportHolder      =response.success;
            $scope.examReportHolderCode  =200;
     })
      .error(function(response){

            $scope.commonExamTemplate    =false;
            $scope.examReportHolder      =[];
            $scope.examReportHolderCode  =502;
            toaster.pop('error','Connection Issue','Bad Network Connection.');
      });

}




}])
.directive('examSheet',function(){

    return{
        templateUrl :'templates/exam/commonexamlist.html',  //i am //loding my template now here in this template i want to print the value of //`$scope.examReportHolder`,which contineously showing me [] as i defined it //initially
        controller  :'examController',
        value       :examReportHolder

    }
```

**and my html**

```
<div ng-if="examReportHolderCode==200" exam-sheet>here i am </div>
```

**and my commonexamlist.html**

```
 <div class="row  text-center">
                  {{examReportHolder}}
                  {{valuee}}
                  </div>
```

Comment: probably you have to define your variables  in the link function of the directive. Now it seems that you have an isolated $scope. Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: What is the issue? Add comments in your code, particularly where you think the code fails - it's hard to understand what's happening / what should happen and isn't

Comment: @callmekatootie : EDITED MY CODE with comments

Comment: Can you show your `commonexamlist.html` contents?

Comment: commonexamlist.html is there in my question

Comment: Is angService using `$http` to get the data? if not try `$scope.$apply()` after updating the values.

Comment: @VinayK yes angService is using $http onlu

Comment: I'm looking at your code thinking that you might want to call `angService.getfromRemote` from within the examController.

Comment: in other words, I can see that your `examSheet` directive has a controller associated with it, but I don't see where the variables are `binded` to your HTML. Maybe I'm missing something on the controller aspect of it.